# Access variable in Ember controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

how can I access a variable in Ember controller?
I've tried those methods, but it doesn't work:

```
import ObjectController from '@ember/controller';
export default ObjectController.extend({

  currentPhase: 1,

  init: function () {
      var selfReference = this;
      this.set("currentPhase",1);
  },

  strings: {
      title: "Title",
      phase1: "Fase " + selfReference.get("currentPhase"),
      phase2: "Fase " + currentPhase
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such cases you would make use of a [computed property](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/object-model/computed-properties/):

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
  currentPhase: 1,

  strings: computed('currentPhase', function() {
    let currentPhase = this.get('currentPhase');
    return {
      title: "Title",
      phase1: `Phase ${currentPhase}`,
      phase2: `Phase ${currentPhase}`
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Init is only ever run once, since your default is is 1 the init call is redundant, as a side note when you overwrite methods from the base object always call `this._super(...arguments);`.

Object controllers are no longer a thing, I understand that this is just naming but such terminology will confuse people.

Get current phase once and save it to a variable there is no need to make multiple `get` calls for the same value.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have defined `selfReference` in your init function, but you tried to reach it from outside of the function which is forbidden. In order to reach it from outside the function, you need to set it to a variable by using `set` function. You can consider defining `strings` as `computed property` as well. Take a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e8bd03c56d526e189df97e75890a46fb?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C).